# If $g \in L^1(\mu)$ and $|f| \leq g$ almost everywhere, then $f \in L^1$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $L^1$ the space of a.e.-defined complex-valued integrable functions on $X$. I am going through the proof of Fatou's lemma, and I've encountered the line:

> since $g \in L^1(\mu)$ and $|f| \leq g$ almost everywhere, then $f \in L^1$.

This makes complete sense intuitively, but I can't seem to prove it using finer details. In particular, I have that $|f| \leq g$ a.e. implies $|f| \leq |g|$ a.e., so $\int|f| \leq \int|g| < \infty$, but I'm not sure if the last implication ($\int |f| \leq \int |g|$) holds from just claiming $|f| \leq |g|$ a.e. Am I missing something or just overanalyzing things?

Comment: The lebesgue integral is monotonic: if $f \leq g$, then $\int f \leq \int g$. Measuure theory doesn't care about sets of measure zero, so the hint is almost a trivaility. Indeed, one usually proves that functions belong in certain function spaces by bounding norms above by elements in the desired function space

Comment: well, you could use $\int|g|=\int|f|+\int(|g|-|f|)\geq\int|f|$...

Comment: Note that $g$ is positive almost everywhere, so $g=|g|$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because integration is monotone, you get 
$$\int |f|d\mu \leqslant \int gd\mu <\infty$$
so that $f$ is $1$-integrable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works.

If you want to elaborate a bit more you can split $\int |f|$ as $\int_A |f| + \int_B |f|$ where $A:=\{x\colon |f(x)|\le g(x)\}$ and $B:=\{x\colon |f(x)|>g(x)\}$ and see that $B$ has null measure by hypothesis.

Comment: We can claim $B$ has null measure by using the completion of $\mu$ (since $L^1(\mu)$ and $L^1(\overline{\mu})$ have one-to-one correspondence), correct?

Comment: $B$ has null measure by definition of "$|f|\le g $ a.e.". In other words, "almost everywhere" means "always apart from a set of null measure". You can probably see it also your way if you feel it is simpler :)

Comment: Oh duh... I think I am trying too hard to approach this theory from the ground up and accidentally foregoing the tools developed to simplify things...

Answer (score 0):

a.e. means with respect to $\mu$, but it is common not to denote it explicitly because it is usually clear from context. That being said, $|f|\leq|g|$ a.e. means $|f|\leq|g|$ at every point except for a set $Z$ with $\mu(Z)=0$, and this implies $\int|f|\leq\int|g|$.